# var keyword turns black instead of blue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, keyword

Sometimes I get this strange behaviour in Visual Studio (both versions 2012 and 2013).

[image]

The `var` keyword simply turns black as if it isn't a keyword at all. If I want it to be blue again I have to delete it and write it again. Why?

It is not a deal-breaker but it irritates me because I use `var` pretty often. I can reproduce it by writting, for instance, `var test = "test";` first and then writting on a line above another expression using `var`.

Comment: noticed the same behaviour, guess you use vs 2012 ?

Comment: @CSharpie I used to use it, now I am using VS 2013 Ulti RC. But the problem remains.

Comment: it's simply a bug. The solution is `wait for the next version`.

Comment: Do you get any `error message`?

Comment: What do those green squiggles represent in this case? (What happens if you hover over them?) Can't say I've ever seen this behaviour myself. (I see it go black while I don't have valid code, but it fixes itself by the time I've finished the statement above...)

Comment: @KingKing Nope, no error. Perfectly compileable code.

Comment: @JonSkeet That the variables are never used in the code. I was just reproducing the bug.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't. Other keywords are always blue, even if the expression is not finished yet.

Comment: I have seen fairly lot of `code formatting bugs` in `VS 2010 Ultimate`, and it may still exist in next versions.

Comment: As King King mentioned, it seems like a bug. Does building the code also fix it?

Comment: @keyboardP As I have stated, sometimes it turns blue once the code does not contain any compile-time erros and sometimes it does not turn blue until I delete at least one letter of `var` and write it again.

Comment: I repro.  Nothing you are we can do about, file bug reports at connect.microsoft.com